# Normalize whitespace in mixed-content elements, in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

[EDIT: Changed title to better conceptualize the question.]

The value of the attribute `@xml:space` can be either `"default"` or `"preserve"`. XML specifies what the second means but leaves the first up to the application. (I think I have that correct.) So what if the application wants `default` to implement XSchema's `collapse`? How could XSLT 1.0 actually do this?

I think the built-in template for processing text, that is,

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

would need to be replaced with something like this pseudo-code:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="../@xml:space='preserve'"
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>

      if position(.)=1 then output LTRIM(value-of(.))
      if position(.)=last() then output RTRIM(value-of(.))
      if position(.)= 1 and last()=1 then output normalize-space(.)

   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This input then:

```
<persName> The man is 
   <forename>Edward</forename>

   <forename>George</forename>
   <surname type="linked">Bulwer-Lytton</surname>, <roleName>Baron Lytton of
   <placeName>Knebworth</placeName>
   </roleName>
</persName>
```

would get rendered correctly as `The man is Edward George Bulwer-Lytton, Baron Lytton of Knebworth` with the space before `The man` and after `Knebworth` trimmed and the spaces between `Edward` and `George` collapsed. (The example is from TEI.)

[EDIT: I removed an incorrect and misleading paragraph here.]

The XSLT 1.0 to implement that pseudo-code would need to be executed for every text node. Wouldn't that be ugly and slow? [EDIT: Or maybe not. I simplified the pseudo code. Are there fast trim routines? Is the choose really that slow?]

Bottom line: How does one implement XSchema's collapse in XSLT 1.0 (with only browser-embedded extensions)?

I hope I'm saying all that correctly. And I hope the code is simple. I haven't yet seen how it can be. [EDIT: Changed xs:collapse to XSchema's collapse.]

Comment: By your rules, there should be a space before the comma in the output. If not, you need to update the question and add an exception.

Comment: I don't see why. There is no space between the close </surname> and the comma.

Comment: Nor is there space between <surname> and "Bulwer-Lytton" and yet in output it is preceded by a space. There is no difference in the cases between Bulwer-Lytton and ", ". If the same rule applies, then both text nodes must be preceded by a space in the output, or both not.

Comment: The space between George and Bulwer-Lytton is caused by the space between </forename> and <surname>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked at xml-dev, and it turns out I was correct about the meaning and intended use of @xml:space.

Here is code to normalize whitespace in mixed-content elements (that's a better way to say what I wanted to do):

```
<xsl:template priority=".7" match="text()[position()=1 and not((ancestor::node()/@xml:space)[position()=last()]='preserve')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring(., string-length(.))) = ''">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template priority=".7" match="text()[position()=last() and not((ancestor::node()/@xml:space)[position()=last()]='preserve')]">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring(., 1, 1)) = ''">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template priority=".8" match="text()[position()=1 and position()=last() and not((ancestor::node()/@xml:space)[position()=last()]='preserve')]" >
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Filtering on `@xml:space` allows `preserve` to override. The `test=` is just a way to test for whitespace. The priorities resolve the conflict caused when a node is the only text node in an element, and thus both the first and the last.

Comment: No, the answers you got on xml-dev just confirmed that the "default" value is meaningless, because everyone's preferences for "default" vary widely. It is OK that someone has a definite preference for `xml:space` processing. It is **not OK** for any individual to force this understanding on other people. Therefore, a correct solution would be either to use your custom attribute (and not `xml:space="default"`) -- for example: `JPMSpace='default'` or to specify some custom value for `xml:space` -- for example: `xml:space="JPMsDefault"`

Comment: I disagree. My assumption was correct and xml-dev confirmed it: xml:space signals whether space within the element should be preserved or may be processed as an application deems appropriate. That signal *is not* limited to treatment of whitespace-only text nodes. Nor, as you note, does the signal specify what the default should be. But the OP was simply a request for code that an application could use if *its* default was to "collapse" or "normalize" white space when xml:space is not set to "preserve". (More on this app'n at http://tinyurl.com/c3vme3c.)

Comment: I don't think it would be correct for a program to have "its" default for space handling -- this may be rather different and undesirable for the author of the XML document. As `xml:space="default"` has not any W3C assigned meaning, this attribute value is meaningless and shouldn't be relied upon for any consistent/conventional space handling.

Comment: Unfortunately, programs do have defaults for space handling (web browsers do, even XSLT does) and, again unfortunately, many XML-using communities rely on the default processing. TEI users have come to expect normalization. I didn't tell them to, but now that they have done it, my application needs to normalize and to refrain from normalizing when xml:space='preserve'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something close to what you want ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  

<xsl:template match="/">
Demonstration of collapsed white space.
=======================================
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.),' ')" />  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces output ...

```
Demonstration of collapsed white space.
=======================================
The man is Edward George Bulwer-Lytton , Baron Lytton of Knebworth
```

Answer (score 0):

**You haven't understood correctly the definition of `xml:space`.**

It only applies to *whitespace-only text nodes*. It doesn't apply to whitespace characters (also called "significant white space") that are contained in a text node that also has non-whitespace characters.

**From the [XML 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-white-space)**:

> "*On the other hand, "significant" white space that should be
>   preserved in the delivered version is common, for example in poetry
>   and source code*"

**Therefore, the whole idea of "trimming" text nodes has nothing to do with `xml:space`.**

**[This resource](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/)** contains an easy to understand explanation of the `xml:space` attribute.

**Update**:

The OP in an answer has changed his initial requirements. Now all he wants is (if my understanding of his answer is correct) to delete the first (and I also think the last) whitespace-only text node in all whitespace-only text nodes that have the same parent.

**This is straightforward -- just add this template to the XSLT stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:template match=
   "text()[not(normalize-space())][position() = 1 or position() = last()]"/>
```

Comment: See extended comment added as an answer. I believe you and xmlplease are wrong about the meaning of space in @xml:space. It is not the same as in xsl:strip-space.

Answer (score 0):

Good edit. Thanks Dimitre.

I'm not convinced I am reading the spec wrong, but assume for a moment I am; let me just fix up my example (which maybe I should have left as it came to me).

```
<persName>
   <forename>Edward</forename>
   <forename>George</forename>
   <surname type="linked">Bulwer-Lytton</surname>, <roleName>Baron Lytton of
   <placeName>Knebworth</placeName>
   </roleName>
</persName>
```

I want the default handling to be that the whitespace-only text node just before `<forename>Edward</forename>` be deleted but not the whitespace-only text node just after `<forename>Edward</forename>`.

But also, it is not clear to me that xml:space refers only to inclusion or deletion of whitespace-only text nodes, as xsl:strip-space, for example, does. Indeed, 2.10 White Space Handling uses, as you note, poetry and source code as examples. Those are cases where the space is inside a text node. @xml:space identifies how that space should be handled. Should it be preserved or handled in the application's default way?

I think http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/ is wrong on this.

Comment: I think that the spec is often not completely precise. The fact is how all implementations interprete it -- and up to my knowledge, all threat `xml:space` as pertaining to whitespace-only text nodes. It would be useful to ask @MichaelKay about this.

Comment: JPM: See the update to my question. I don't think "default" should be treated in a generally-specified way (not implementation-specific) because different people have different preferences on what "default" should mean in this case. This is most likely the W3C working group decided to leave this implementation-dependent.

Comment: Dimitre, what would be a good forum on which to ask about this?

Comment: Dimitre, I confirmed my understanding of @xml:space and posted a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your previous answer...if you have a file that looks like this

```
<document>
<p>A paragraph of text with subtags (whitespace after; no whitespace only between): Lorem
        <italic>Before/After</italic> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim <italic>Before/After</italic>
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>A paragraph of text with subtags (whitespace between: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <italic>Before/After</italic>
    <italic>Before/After</italic> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, <italic>Before/After</italic> <italic>Before/After</italic> laboris nisi ut aliquip 
    ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</document>
```

Then the bits between the italic tags won't get caught by your normalize-space templates because they are neither at the start nor the end of the block.

As far as I can tell you have to add a fourth one to check for opening and closing space (and keep it) then normalize the stuff in between.

```
<xsl:template priority=".7" match="text()[not(position()=1) and not(position()=last()) 
    and not((ancestor::node()/@xml:space)[position()=last()]='preserve')]" >
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring(., 1, 1)) = ''">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring(., string-length(.), 1)) = ''">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```